# Why hasNextLine() blocks executing of program while getting data from console?

Tags: java

Today I was trying to write some, lets say, internet communicator.
I'm learning basics of Java (from instructables) and now it's time for network programming.
What I want my program to do:
If there is any data on input stream from network - get data, put it into string and print in a console.
If there is data in console - put it into string and send it by network.

When I try only send data from client app to server and print it in server console - everything works fine. But then I have different code (without getting and sending data two way).
I know that problem is in lines inside while(true) statements in line if(cin.hasNextLine()). I don't understand why it blocks whole app when it should be just returning false or true if there isn't or there is data in console (from keyboard).

The annoying is that it's working perfectly with reading files.

Oh. And also I tried to check IF data which I didn't typed into console is "". It didn't solved my problem.

Server code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class GreetingServer extends Thread {
        private ServerSocket serverSocket;

        public GreetingServer(int port) throws IOException {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 0);
                serverSocket.setSoTimeout(30000);
        }

        public void run() {
                while(true) {
                        try {
                                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");

                                Socket server = serverSocket.accept();

                                System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
                                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
                                out.writeUTF("Thank you for connecting to " + server.getLocalSocketAddress());
                                FileWriter plik = new FileWriter("/home/greg/Dokumenty/logizserwera.txt", true);
                                System.out.println("StartTime: " + LocalTime.now());

                                Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
                                String stringReadyToSend, stringGotFromClient = null;
                                while(true) {
                                        System.out.println("Before hasnextline");
                                        if(cin.hasNextLine()) {
                                                stringReadyToSend = cin.nextLine();
                                                out.writeUTF(stringReadyToSend);
                                        }

                                        if(in.available() != 0) {
                                                stringGotFromClient = in.readUTF();
                                                // EOT means End Of Transmission
                                                if(stringGotFromClient.equals("EOT")) break;
                                                else System.out.println("Message from client: " + stringGotFromClient();
                                        }
                                        else System.out.println("No message");

                                break;
                                }

                                System.out.println("EndTime: " + LocalTime.now());
                                server.close();
                                plik.close();
                        }
                        catch(SocketTimeoutException s) {
                                System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
                                break;
                        }
                        catch(IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                int port = 6066;
                try {
                        Thread t = new GreetingServer(port);
                        t.start();
                }catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

And client code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GreetingClient {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                String serverName = "localhost";
                Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
                int port = 6066;
                try {
                        System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
                        Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
                        System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                        OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
                        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
                        out.writeUTF("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
                        InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
                        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
                        System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
                        String lineReadyToSend, lineGotFromServer;

                        while(cin.hasNextLine()) {
                                if(cin.hasNextLine()) {
                                        // EOT means End Of Transmission
                                        lineReadyToSend = cin.nextLine();
                                        if(lineReadyToSend.equals("EOT")) {
                                                out.writeUTF(lineReadyToSend);
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        else out.writeUTF(lineReadyToSend);
                                }
                                if(in.available() != 0) {
                                        lineGotFromServer = in.readUTF();
                                        System.out.println("Message from server: " + lineGotFromServer);
                                }
                        }

                        out.writeUTF("EOT");
                        client.close();
                        System.out.println("End of transmission. Server disconnected");

                }catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify more... Where is the error exactly?

Comment: The docs for Scanner make it very clear it may block.

Comment: @Mackiavelli: Hm... Look at the while() loop in server code.
2 lines lower there is this: if(cin.hasNextLine()). I want to only check there if there is any new data in console from user, where server app is running. If there is no new data I want to go further to receive data from input stream and print it in console.
It works, but I get data printed in console only if I send to app or to server something.
I just want to print received data no matter if there is or there isn't new data in console running app or server.

Comment: if you do not want it to block in your if(cin.hasNextLine()), use  if(System.in.available()>0)

Answer (score 0):

You are using cin which is a Scanner for the System.in

Practically that just scans if there are entered lines on the console. Perhaps try doing that with the data input stream (in) on your server.

Comment: But in is for data sent from other app, not from console where app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Well, everything looks god. Just a cuestion, do you execute both applications at same time? Well, if it's the case, could be the access to `System.in` resource. Remember this is a static field, and not instantiated. Try to run one of them in other location. A second hint: use `try` clause and watch the errors if there are, and use debuging or resource monitor tools to detect the problem.

Comment: Yes. I execute both apps at the same time (of course in other consoles). I know where bug is (it's in line if(cin.hasNextLine(), because it's working like, I think, if there is no new data in console it waits for data. Obviously I want it to go further and execute next block of code which gets data sent from other app and print it into console. It works only if I put lines in both apps then it's like: put data in server/client app so I will print you data received from client/server app.